# PDF file upload with HTTPS POST request (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

I've been trying to upload a PDF file with a form-encoded HTTPS request. In my method below, I can successfully upload a text file but when I try with a PDF, I get a forbidden error (403). I've been searching the web for an answer but found no hint on how to fix this...

I tried the WriteAllBytes and CopyTo methods to convert the PDF then write it to the stream, but I got the same error both times.

```cs
public void CreateFile(string parentID, string filePath)
{
    Stream stream;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower().Replace(".", "");
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://someurl/upload/");

    string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Credentials = ConnectedUser.AssignedOwner.NetworkCredentials;

    var data = "--" + boundary + "\n"; 
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"parent\"\n\n" + parentID + "\n"; 
    data += "--" + boundary + "\n"; 
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\n";
    data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";

    switch (extension)
    {
        // This works
        case "txt":
            data += "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
            data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";

            data += File.ReadAllText(filePath) + "\n";
            data += "--" + boundary + "--\n";

            var bData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = bData.Length;

            stream = request.GetRequestStream();           
            stream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
            break;

        // This doesn't work
        case "pdf":
            using (var s = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                data += "Content-Type: application/pdf\n";
                data += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n";

                byte[] bDataPDF = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                string footer = "--" + boundary + "--\n";
                byte[] bFooter = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(footer);
                request.ContentLength = bDataPDF.Length + s.Length + bFooter.Length;

                stream = request.GetRequestStream();
                stream.Write(bDataPDF, 0, bDataPDF.Length);
                s.CopyTo(stream);
                stream.Write(bFooter, 0, bFooter.Length);  
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```